# Highcharts context buttons placement at top of graph beside legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a simple way of placing the export button outside the data area at the same level as the legend ? I've tried every combo of align and vertical align, but I can;t seem to get it out/up.

e.g.
contextButton: {
align: 'right',
verticalAlign: 'top',
text: 'EXPORT'
} doesn't work,

nor does any combination of setting the x, y values

[image]

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=32810

Comment: Thanks ! I might need to go with something like that and place it outside of the graph altogether. Just to be awkward I wanted it on the same level as the legend, neither above nor below. Maybe it's simply not a feature.

Comment: Hi @orion_kid, Could explain where exactly you want to place the button? Options from the API should be enough, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/frcnybzt/

Comment: @ppotaczek Thanks for the demo. I want it, ideally, at the same level as the legend, 'Aggregate', in my screenshot but right aligned. My chart does not have a title, so this means the export is being rendered on the chart, not above it. If we modify your demo code to have title: { text: '' }, you will see the issue. I might be able to live with legend, then export button slightly below, and then graph data below that.

Comment: You can position the button above the chart by modyfing `y` property and changing overflow style, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ytdh0439/ Or you can also use spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f08Lhz41/